# Fixing margins in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, visualization

I have a plot whose margins are slightly askew and need to be removed.  So there should be no empty grey along the bottom or at the left and right of the plot.  The dots should go right against the axis's.  I think part of the problems may be my last two annotation lines.  I tried adding `+ theme(plot.margins = unit(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), "cm"))` in the last line that defines my plot but this just returns an error:

```
Error: Theme element `plot.margins` is not defined in the element hierarchy.
```

`
[image]

```
 pvalplot<-function(var, maintitle) {
    
    pvalall<-as.data.frame(c(t(var)))
    pvalall$Sample_Size<-c((1:(5*162)),(1:(11*162)),(1:(3*162)),(1:(5*162)),(1:(13*162)),(1:(3*162)),(1:(5*162)))
    pvalall$Domain<-c(rep("Physical",5*162),rep("Perinatal",11*162),rep("Developmental",3*162),
                      rep("Lifestyle-Life Events",5*162),rep("Parental-Family",13*162),rep("School",3*162),
                      rep("Neighborhood",5*162))
    pvalall$Domain <- factor(pvalall$Domain,
                             levels = c("Physical", "Perinatal", "Developmental", 
                                        "Lifestyle-Life Events", "Parental-Family",
                                        "School","Neighborhood"))
    pvalall[,1]<-ifelse(pvalall[,1]<1e-20,1e-20,pvalall[,1])
    
    names(pvalall)[1]<-"P-Values"
    
    pvalexp.labels= rep("",45*162)
    for (i in c(1:45)){
      j=i*162-81
      pvalexp.labels[j]=rownames(var)[i]
    } #makes list of empyt labels that w
    
    p<-ggplot(pvalall,aes(x = 1:nrow(pvalall), y = -log10(pvalall[,1])))+
      geom_point(aes(color = Domain,size=5),
                 alpha = 0.7, size=1)
    p+ylab(expression(atop(" -log10(P-Values)")))+
      ylim(0,20)+
      xlab(element_blank())+
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
      scale_x_continuous( breaks=c(1:45)*162-81, labels = rownames(var))+
      theme_classic()+
      theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
      theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank())+
      theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 25))+
      theme(text = element_text(size=25))+
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
      theme(legend.position=c(0.8,0.7))+
      geom_abline(slope=0,intercept=-log10(c(var)[astsa::FDR(c(var))]),linetype = "dashed")+
      geom_abline(slope=0,intercept=5.2,linetype = "dashed")+
      ggtitle(maintitle)+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      theme(
        legend.box.background = element_rect(),
        legend.box.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6))+
      theme_update(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 35, size = 6.5, vjust = 1, hjust=1, color = "black")) +
      annotate("text",  label = expression(paste("FDR P-value","=0.05")),size=5, x=1000,y=-log10(c(var)[astsa::FDR(c(var))])-0.5, color="black",parse=TRUE)+
      annotate("text",  label = expression(paste("Bonferroni P-value","=0.05")),size=5, x=1200,y=5.7, color="black",parse=TRUE)
  }#end of plotting
```

Comment: It's `plot.margin` not margin**s**. (;

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a line

```
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
```

in your plot command chain.

Comment: thank you for that that fixes that problem but introduces another,  I did that for the scale_x_continuous( breaks=c(1:45)*162-81, labels = rownames(var))+ as well maming it scale_x_continuous( breaks=c(1:45)*162-81, labels = rownames(var), expand =c(0,0) ) but now my title plot is not centered you wills ee I've added the correct hadjust line so it should be working.  I tried moving the order of my commands around but that didn't fix it either.